# How do you pass data from main.qml to main.py then send it to other qml files

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I want to send data from the textfield to the backend which is the main.py file. A function will then concatenate the string "Welcome" by adding what the input was in the textfield. This string will then be displayed in a label which is found in a third file through a stackpush on the main page. After connecting the Backend and front end my program only displays Welcome without the textfield input

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.fill: parent

        StackView {
            id: stackView
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: button.top
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            anchors.topMargin: 5
        }

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 368
            y: 396
            text: qsTr("Button")
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            onClicked: stackView.push("home.qml")
            onPressed: {
                backend.welcomeText(txtName.text)
            }
        }

        TextField {
            id: txtName
            x: 92
            y: 436
            placeholderText: qsTr("Text Field")
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: backend

        function onGetName(name){
            welcomeLabel.text = name
        }
    }
}

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;formeditorZoom:0.75}D{i:2}D{i:1}
}
##^##*/
```

home.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#262626"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Label {
            id: welcomeLabel
            x: 251
            y: 204
            width: 251
            height: 82
            color: "#e9eaeb"
            text: qsTr("Welcome")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }

}
```

main.py

```
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal

class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    #getName
    getName = Signal(str)

    @Slot(str)
    def welcomeText(self, name):
        self.getName.emit("Welcome " + name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    main = MainWindow()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that welcomeLabel only has a scope of "home.qml" so it is not defined in main.qml.

Since "backend" is a contextProperty it has a global scope (something like a global variable) so you must make the connection of the "getName" signal in home.qml. But the problem is that you are emitting the signal before the page is loaded so the connection will not work, in this case the solution is to first load and then invoke the slot.

The solution in your practical case:

1. Move the "Connections" code from main.qml to home.qml
2. and change(remove `pressed`):

```
onClicked: {
    stackView.push("home.qml")
    backend.welcomeText(txtName.text)
}
```

Comment: I performed your solution but now when i click on the button nothing happens. There home.qml does not get pushed to the stackview

Comment: oh! My bad. I left out a curly brace. Runs perfectly fine now